# How to add an field type conditions on GlideRecord?

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I need create an GlideRecord for table X and queries but one of parameter is a condition type and other is table_name type because the query is dynamic.

if i trying, alert "invalid table name: null".

My code:

```
var tableQueried = new GlideRecord(current.u_ruta);
tableQueried.addQuery(current.u_filtro);
tableQueried.query();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this question, it turns out that the condition type field is treated as a string so it is very simple to use, there really was no need to post my question here.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:-

One is using encoded query with the condition instead of the `addQuery()` method:

```
tableQueried.addEncodedQuery(current.u_filtro);
```

But the preferred method to avoid errors is [`GlideFilter.checkRecord()`](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/orlando/server/no-namespace/c_GlideFilterScopedAPI). You can use it as:

```
var tableQueried = new GlideRecord(current.u_rota);
tableQueried.query();
while(tableQueried.next()){
  if(GlideFilter.checkRecord(tableQueried, current.u_filtro)){
     //Do something
  }
}
```